# How do I use this cp command properly

Tags: linux, find, xargs

How do I use the below properly:
I want to find all files belonging to user and copy them in a folder.

`find / -user Joe | xargs -I {} cp {} /home/Joe/Folder`

The commands hangs and on `ctrl C` it prints a **0** that represents something.

Answer (score 1):

```
find / -user Joe -exec cp {} /home/Joe/Folder \;
```

This will also copy for instance filenames with whitespace in them.

If you insist on using xargs as well:

```
find / -user Joe -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} cp {} /home/Joe/Folder
```

`find`'s option `-print0` will make it terminate filenames with a `nul`, while for `xargs` `-0` will make it accept (only) filenames ending in `nul`. The effect of this is to ensure that for instance filenames with whitespace in them will also be seen correctly by `xargs`, and will be acted upon accordingly (in this case copied elsewhere).

Finally, please be aware that your `cp` command as is will *not* copy directories or their contents; you would need the additional `cp` options `-dR`. See `man 1 cp`.

Comment: Thank your very much for the explanation and example

Comment: I am running into an issue sometimes when using the above command find / -user Joe -exec cp {} /home/Joe/Folder \;  No disk space left on drive.  I am guessing I need to make sure the partition is very large, there is 8Gb.  Also when I run the find command by itself it pulls like 200 files but when I run the command in full it pulls way more then intended. Curious why?